# Trying to access array offset on value of type null (Lumen QueueManager.php)

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have this code, but it throw an error when i try to use it even in simplest way.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class RefreshUploadedFileId extends Job
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('Hi, you reached here!');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
use App\Jobs\RefreshUploadedFileId;

dispatch(new RefreshUploadedFileId);
```

Error message:

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null at /home/***/public_html/vendor/illuminate/queue/QueueManager.php:156
```

> PHP version: ^8.0
>
> Lumen version: ^8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with changing QUEUE_CONNECTION from `file` to `sync`.